# How can I change UIButton title color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I create a button programmatically..........

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

how can I change title color?

Answer (score 555, accepted):

You can use `-[UIButton setTitleColor:forState:]` to do this.

Example:

**Objective-C**

```
[buttonName setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Swift 2**

```
buttonName.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

**Swift 3**

```
buttonName.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
```

Thanks to [richardchildan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87601/richardchildan)

Comment: For instance [buttonName setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: I can't believe [UIButton setTitleColor:forState:] works but btn.titleColor = [UIColor x] does not..

Comment: @Lengus I don't see how you can access `btn.titleColor`, there is just `btn setTitleColor` available

Comment: Superb answer. Its ridiculous how you have to set the state just to change the color though... :(

Comment: How about with RGB ?

Answer (score 25):

You created the `UIButton` is added the `ViewController`, The following instance method to change `UIFont`, `tintColor` and `TextColor` of the `UIButton`

**Objective-C**

```
 buttonName.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"LuzSans-Book" size:15];
 buttonName.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
 [buttonName setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Swift**

```
buttonName.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "LuzSans-Book", size: 15)
buttonName.tintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
buttonName.setTitleColor(UIColor.purpleColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

**Swift3**

```
buttonName.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "LuzSans-Book", size: 15)
buttonName.tintColor = UIColor.purple
buttonName.setTitleColor(UIColor.purple, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Please don't simply post the code. Give some explanation or information or usage about your code. For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16893057/756941).

Answer (score 3):

**Solution** in **Swift 3**:

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
```

This will set the title color of button.

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 5, `UIButton` has a [`setTitleColor(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623993-settitlecolor) method. `setTitleColor(_:for:)` has the following declaration:

> Sets the color of the title to use for the specified state.

```
func setTitleColor(_ color: UIColor?, for state: UIControlState)
```

---

The following Playground sample code show how to create a `UIbutton` in a `UIViewController` and change it's title color using `setTitleColor(_:for:)`:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // Create button
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)

        // Set button's attributes
        button.setTitle("Print 0", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: UIControl.State.normal)

        // Set button's frame
        button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        button.sizeToFit()

        // Add action to button
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(printZero(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

        // Add button to subView
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func printZero(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("0")
    }

}

let controller = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swift, this will do the same:

`buttonName.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)`

Hope that helps!