# UIButton title text color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, textcolor

I'm setting text color for `UIButton`

```
headingButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 
                                                     green:71/255.0 
                                                      blue:113/255.0 
                                                     alpha:1.0];
```

It's not changing color same code I'm using in another code it's working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change UIButton title color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474289/how-can-i-change-uibutton-title-color)

Answer (score 472, accepted):

use

**Objective-C**

```
[headingButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 green:71/255.0 blue:113/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**Swift**

```
headingButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
```

Comment: this works.  but the code in the original question also often works.  anyone know why the title only sometimes fails to respond to the code in the question?

Comment: The reason is that when the button is clicked or otherwise changes state, the code in the button resets the titleLabel's properties to match the internal settings the button has for that state.

Comment: the documentation of apple states the following : "Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color. Instead, use the setTitleColor:forState: and setTitleShadowColor:forState: methods of this class to make those changes."  No real explanation of the "why" though.

Comment: MOST IMPORTANTLY when you set a color for UIControlStateNormal, there is no need to set it for all the other states (if you want your button to look the same when pressed).

Comment: how to change button text color globally in app delegate. Maybe using UIButton.appearance().setTitleColor?

Answer (score 6):

I created a custom class **MyButton** extended from `UIButton`. Then added this inside the `Identity Inspector`:

[image]

After this, change the button type to **Custom**:

[image]

Then you can set attributes like `textColor` and `UIFont` for your `UIButton` for the different states:

[image]

Then I also created two methods inside `MyButton` class which I have to call inside my code when I want a `UIButton` to be displayed as highlighted:

```
- (void)changeColorAsUnselection{
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:acColorGreyDark] 
               forState:UIControlStateNormal & 
                        UIControlStateSelected & 
                        UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

- (void)changeColorAsSelection{
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:acColorYellow] 
               forState:UIControlStateNormal & 
                        UIControlStateHighlighted & 
                        UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

You have to set the `titleColor` for normal, highlight and selected `UIControlState` because there can be more than one state at a time according to the documentation of `UIControlState`.
If you don't create these methods, the `UIButton` will display selection or highlighting but they won't stay in the `UIColor` you setup inside the `UIInterface Builder` because they are just available for a short display of a selection, not for displaying selection itself.

Comment: Shouldn't the last code snippet use `|` instead of `&`?

Answer (score 5):

**In Swift:**

Changing the label text color is quite different than changing it for a `UIButton`. To change the text color for a `UIButton` use this method:

```
self.headingButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 107.0/255.0, green: 199.0/255.0, blue: 217.0/255.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

> **swift 5 version:**

***By using default inbuilt color:***

1. `button.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)`

OR

***You can use your custom color by using RGB method:***

2. `button.setTitleColor(UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.0/255.0, green: 180.0/255.0, blue: 2.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)`

Answer (score 1):

Besides de color, my problem was that I was setting the text using textlabel

```
bt.titleLabel?.text = title
```

and I solved changing to:

```
bt.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
```