# Change the color and alignment of a UIButton's text

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton

I am creating a `UIButton` in a `UITableView`:

```
UIButton *aboutButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[aboutButton setTitle:@"ABOUT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aboutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aboutButtonClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
aboutButton.frame=CGRectMake(20, 375, 200, 35);
[tableView addSubView aboutButton];
```

The button is working fine......... but the button text is in blue color and center-aligned. I want to change the text color and alignment - how do I do this?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=uibutton+text+color&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=X16lTA4rR-i6Vx88X1hsGA&pq=uibutton%20text%20color&cp=15&gs_id=1p&xhr=t&q=uibutton+text+alignment&pf=p&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&oq=uibutton+text+a&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6fc3f1821ef6f8e6&biw=1127&bih=986

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=uibutton+text+color&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=uibutton+title+color&oq=uibutton+title+color&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30l3.54528.57959.3.58134.13.9.1.3.3.3.1674.7772.4-1j2j2j1j2.8.0...0.0...1c.1.8KcagvrnVw0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6fc3f1821ef6f8e6&biw=1127&bih=986

Comment: This really should could been solved with a click glance at the `UIButton` and `UILabel` class references, there was no need to post this on SO. You can view the docs in Xcode or on the web, they are quite straightforward and detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set button title color & Alignment ...

```
[aboutButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[aboutButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

or

```
aboutButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

or

```
[aboutButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight];
```

Comment: [aboutButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter]; is not working....

Comment: Use this code [aboutButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight];

Comment: aboutButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; is working

Comment: by default it is centre aligned... but if i use aboutButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft, it is still centre..

Comment: [aboutButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16402/discussion-between-vikas-rajput-and-venkat)

Answer (score 1):

```
[aboutButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
[aboutButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
```

it has been asked several times in SO

[button alignment question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765024/how-to-set-the-title-as-left-alignment-in-the-uibutton)

[another button alignment question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712937/how-to-make-uibuttons-text-alignment-center)

[button title color question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703699/uibutton-title-text-color)

[another button title color question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474289/how-can-i-change-uibutton-title-color)

Answer (score 0):

You use `-[myButton setTitleColor:forState:]` for setting the color of the title.
The alignment can be changed with `[myButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight]`

Comment: You can set the button frame.