# iOS Change Color Of UiButton not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uicolor

When my viewcontroller initially loads my font color doesnt change.  But if I go to another viewcontroller and then go back to this viewcontroller my button font finally changes color. I've tried adding the code below to the `viewwillappear` and `viewdidload`:

```
self.SaveBTN.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Any Idea as to why the font color only changes when i go to another view controller and then switch back but not on the initial first load of the page?

Flow of app:

```
Navigation Controller -> tab bar Controller -> view controller (button is here)
```

Comment: If you want to change the color of the actual button, why don't don't you use self.SaveBTN.view.backgroundColor() = UIColor.blueColor()?

Comment: i want to change the font color not the background color

Comment: The first part of your question is unclear. I advise you edit it.

Comment: I've edited my question, hopefully it's more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SaveBTN.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)` in the viewDidLoad function.

Comment: it works on the initial load now, thanks!  any idea as to why my code above didn't work on the initial load?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. Using setTitleColor is the correct convention. Someone suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703699/uibutton-title-text-color that the color reverts back to the original color set in the IB, but I do not know if that is the actual reason for this. Apple does not give any clear answer either.