# How to set the title color of button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage, uicolor

How can set the `title color` of the button when an image is placed on button.?Any one can help me out this..
My Code for the same is mentioned below:

```
startLoginBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 303, 267, 40)];
[startLoginBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SkipLogin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[startLoginBtn setTitle:@"Start Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[startLoginBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[startLoginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(startLogin:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[startLoginBtn setEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:startLoginBtn];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change UIButton title color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474289/how-can-i-change-uibutton-title-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your image as background image.

Use following code.

```
startLoginBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 303, 267, 40)]; 
[startLoginBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SkipLogin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[startLoginBtn setTitle:@"Start Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[startLoginBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[startLoginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(startLogin:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[startLoginBtn setEnabled:YES]; 
[self.view addSubview:startLoginBtn];
```

Comment: Hey, i am saying that instead of repeating same answer we can upvote first right answer given on question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `setImage` for your button, just use `-[UIButton setBackgroundImage: forState:]`

Comment: have you tried it? use image will overlay the title, just use backgroundimage, it will under your title. Hope this could help.

Comment: When I read his question I did not see your answer till the page refresh. :D

Comment: @LalitKumar I'm sure you are having a bad day, dude. Just take some excersie and sleep. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[startLoginBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SkipLogin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

change it to

```
[startLoginBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SkipLogin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this one,

```
    UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [ Button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(YourMethodName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [sectionView addSubview:Button];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```